# PostgreSQL IF EXITS inside a FUNCTION Error 42601

Tags: function, postgresql, if-statement, syntax-error

I want to create a function that will return an integer variable (or boolean) after check if there are any row in table RESERVATION have an RESERVATION_ID that equal to the reser_id I give to it. But my code seem wrong at the IF statement.

This is my query code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE Function fcn_check (reser_id integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TICKET_TICKET WHERE reservation_id = reser_id) )
        THEN SELECT 1 AS result;
    ELSE SELECT 0 AS result;
    END IF;
END     
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

The error messages is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 2:  IF (SELECT * FROM TICKET_TICKET WHERE reservation_id = rese...
         ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 76
```

Im a newbie at pgsql and look like I didnt try hard enough to slove this, but please help me. 
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$ LANGUAGE SQL;

You seem to be writing PL/PgSQL, but you've declared it as SQL.

Use `LANGUAGE plpgsql`.

Comment: Oh thank you! I did it, but still dont know how the $$ work, how many keyword use for it?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: I saw that after "$$" they are nothing, sometime they are "LAGUAGE SQL", sometime are "LANGUAGE plpgsql".
I still cant get what they are meaning.

Comment: Procedures may be written in many programming languages. PL/PgSQL, i.e.`LANGUAGE plpgsql`, is the PostgreSQL procedural variant of SQL. `LANGUAGE sql` is instead a simple SQL function - it just runs plain SQL statements and returns the result of the last one. Other options include `plpythonu`, `plperl`, etc. For more information, see the PostgreSQL manual.

Comment: Thanks alots, I got it ;D